# Is there any way to get honesty in box quest 2?

Tags: succubox

I reset to quest 2 and no longer can buy loot boxes with real money so I can't get honesty is there any way to get it now?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I eventually got it when I "secured" Africa. I don't know exactly the mechanics behind it or why I got it right away for box quest 3.

Maybe just try to wait for a while you, should get it before LVL 90.

Comment: How long did you have to wait?

Comment: at about just after "securing" Africa tho number 3 gave me it right away

Comment: I don't know why it gave me it I just guess it might be random or whatever.

Comment: Hi Dark, you are probably getting down voted because your answer lacks details and specifics.  Simply stating that "you just have to wait" isn't a very good answer - even if it *is* the answer.  Try to add more details, like how long you need to wait, or external sources (if possible) that back up your findings.